# react native passing value

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new in React Native and I searched on Google but I only could find old version of React Native.

Actually, I am not sure how to pass state value to other js files
I am making Authpage that will redirect to tappage.js if the state value 'isValid' becomes 'true'

I am planning to change the page like this on App.js, if there are other better way, please let me know.

Thank you this is my code.
AuthManager.js

```
export default class AuthPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user                    : null,
      firebaseUser            : null,
      fcmToken                : null,
      accessToken             : null,
      authType                : null,
      hasInitialNotification  : null,
      isValid                 : false
    };
    this.unsubscribe = null;

  }

...some codes..


render() {
    // if (!this.state.firebaseUser) {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
        <View style = {styles.main}>


        <View style ={styles.logotemp}>
        <Image style ={styles.logo}
        source={require('../../resources/logo/logo.png')}
        />

        </View>

        <View style = {styles.inputid}>


        <FormInput
        ref={(el)=> {this.email = el;}}
        textInputRef='email'
        placeholder = "Email"
        onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
        value = {this.state.email}
        />

        <FormInput
        ref={(el)=> {this.password = el;}}
        textInputRef='password'
        onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
        value = {this.state.password}
        placeholder = "Password"
        secureTextEntry = {true}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._emailSignIn.bind(this)}>
        <Image
        style = {styles.loginbut}
        source={require('../../resources/socialicon/signin.png')}
        />
        </TouchableOpacity>  

        </View>

        <View style = {styles.socialicons}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._facebookSignIn.bind(this)} >
        <Image 
        style={styles.fbicons}
        source={require('../../resources/socialicon/facebook.png')}
        />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Image
        style={styles.divider}
        source = {require('../../resources/socialicon/divider.png')}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._googleSignIn.bind(this)} >
        <Image
        style={styles.ggicons}
        source={require('../../resources/socialicon/google.png')}
        />
        </TouchableOpacity>  

        </View>    
        </View>

        </Provider>
      );
    // }

    if (this.state.firebaseUser) {
      return(
        <Provider store = {store}>
        {store.isValid = this.state.isValid}
        </Provider>
      );
    }
  }

export default class MainPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }



  render() {
    alert(store.isValid);
    if(!this.props.isValid){
      return(<View style={{flex:1}}>

         <AuthPage></AuthPage> 

        </View>


      );
    }

    if(isValid){
    return(
        <View style={{flex:1}}>

         <TabPage></TabPage>

        </View>
      );
    }




  }
}
```

thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom in React is that only the current element can know it's state.
I would highly recommend using [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) for the global data transfer between components, or, if you do not need data synced, you can use [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html).